# STM32Ethernet UDP misses some packets

Tags: ethernet, stm32

Using STM32Duino on Nucleo F429ZI:

```
#include <LwIP.h>
#include <STM32Ethernet.h>
#define UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE 512
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

IPAddress remoteIP;
unsigned int remotePort;

EthernetUDP Udp;
uint8_t packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  IPAddress localIP = /***/;
  IPAddress netmask = /***/;
  IPAddress dns = /***/;
  IPAddress gateway = /***/;

  Ethernet.begin(localIP, netmask, dns, gateway);
  uint8_t *mac = Ethernet.macAddress();

  int port = 8888;
  Udp.begin(port);
}

void loop() 
{  
  processUDPMessage();
}

void processUDPMessage(void)
{ 
  while (int size = Udp.parsePacket())
  {
    if (size > 0) parsePacket(size);
  } 
}

void parsePacket(int size)
{
  remoteIP = Udp.remoteIP();
  remotePort = Udp.remotePort();

  Udp.read(packetBuffer, size);
  Serial.println((char *) packetBuffer);  
}
```

If I received at least 4 packets at the same time, one of them is not received. Each packet is less than 50 byte long.

Is there anything I could do to improve the reliability of my code?

Comment: are you sure it is STM32duino by Roger Clark and not STM32 by STM? does STM32Duino  support F4 and STM32Ethernet? the experts are here https://www.stm32duino.com

Comment: The STM32 Core is by STM, the STM32duino STM32Ethernet library is by "Various" and STM32duino LwIP is by Adam Dunkels.

Comment: UDP is, by definition, unreliable. If you want more reliability then use TCP.

Comment: @Majenko, sorry I don't agree. This is a problem in my code, not in the UDP protocol. I use it since 10 years and I *never* missed a packet. Here I miss packets *every* time they are sent. It's a different thing :)

Comment: @Mark My point is: that UDP is not a *reliable* protocol ("reliable" has a specific meaning in networking). That means that the protocol that you design with it must be tolerant of dropped packets. Yes, there may well be problems with your code or with the IP stack in use, but if you designed your protocol properly then it shouldn't care that you lost some packets.

Comment: Yes, but this is the second step in my opinion. At first my code should work at least in a predictable environment.